# Using Or and + Criteria in VBA WorksheetFunction.Sumifs

Tags: excel, vba, formula

Hi
I was wondering if there was a way I could conbine these 2 Macros as I want it to Sum `Invoice_list_Price` if it has either or both `"(Custom) CREDIT"` or `"CREDIT"` Criteria,
Thank You.

```
Range("DebtorList_Credit") = Application.SumIfs( _ 
  Range("Invoice_list_Price"), _
  Range("Invoice_list_Debtor"), _
  Range("Debtor_list_Debtors"), _
  Range("InvoiceList_Payed"), _
  "CREDIT")

Range("DebtorList_Credit") = Application.SumIfs( _
  Range("Invoice_list_Price"), _
  Range("Invoice_list_Debtor"), _
  Range("Debtor_list_Debtors"), _
  Range("InvoiceList_Payed"), _
  "(Custom) CREDIT")
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is running? The typical use is this: http://www.excel-examples.com/sumifs.htm

Comment: Yea the code works fine, it just wont let me combine the 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I completely misunderstanding your question, or is this all you're after?

```
Range("DebtorList_Credit") = Application.SumIfs( _ 
  Range("Invoice_list_Price"), _
  Range("Invoice_list_Debtor"), _
  Range("Debtor_list_Debtors"), _
  Range("InvoiceList_Payed"), _
  "CREDIT")

Range("DebtorList_Credit") = Range("DebtorList_Credit") + '<--only change
  Application.SumIfs( _
  Range("Invoice_list_Price"), _
  Range("Invoice_list_Debtor"), _
  Range("Debtor_list_Debtors"), _
  Range("InvoiceList_Payed"), _
  "(Custom) CREDIT")
```

Comment: Got it working using "**" thanks though Nick I had tried that and it wouldn't work for some obscure reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("DebtorList_Credit") = Application.SumIfs( _
Range("Invoice_list_Price"), _  
Range("Invoice_list_Debtor"), _  
Range("Debtor_list_Debtors"), _  
Range("InvoiceList_Payed"), _  
"*CREDIT*")`
```